# Writing to HDFS Using Java

Tags: java, hadoop

I am writing a file to hdfs using java using the following code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;


public class WriteInrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Source file in the local file system
        String localSrc = args[0];
        //Destination file in HDFS
        String dst = args[1];

        //Input stream for the file in local file system to be written to HDFS
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localSrc));

        //Get configuration of Hadoop system
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        System.out.println("Connecting to -- "+conf.get("fs.defaultFS"));

        //Destination file in HDFS
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);
        OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(dst));

        //Copy file from local to HDFS
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);

        System.out.println(dst + " copied to HDFS");

        }
}
```

But I am getting the following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/fs/
>   FSDataOutputStream
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputSt
>   ream
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 6 more

Why I am getting the exception? I just copied the source code from the [Link](http://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/writing-a-file-to-hdfs-java-program/)